# How to change activity and show specific fragment, when the activity loads

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to change activity and show specific fragment, when the activity loads.

I need to change to a activity (B) from activity (A). The second activity (B) is empty fragment with Framelayout to load fragment. Need to load a fragment when the second activity (B) is loaded, already have loaded 02 fragments to load in this Framelayout, now need to load a fragment for map.

How to do this? I was new to android and eager to learn more in it.